# What is the SQL query to return the SQL error log configuration?

Tags: sql-server-2005

What is the SQL query to return the SQL error log configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Error Log Configuration"?

Comment: IN SQL server there is SQL Error log option under the management,
when u right click on that SQL error log option ,its there is option called configure, where we can set Maximum Number of Error Log.

Answer (score 0):

From running SQL Profiler whilst viewing that option in Management Studio it appears to be stored in the registry. The below is what I got. It returns `NULL` if I have the "limit the number of error log files..." option unchecked or the number otherwise.

If it doesn't work for you you might want to try the same thing on your instance to see if the paths are any different.

```
declare @HkeyLocal nvarchar(18)
declare @MSSqlServerRegPath nvarchar(31)
declare @InstanceRegPath sysname

select @HkeyLocal=N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'

-- Instance-based paths
select @MSSqlServerRegPath=N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer'
select @InstanceRegPath=@MSSqlServerRegPath + N'\MSSQLServer'

declare @NumErrorLogs int
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread @HkeyLocal, @InstanceRegPath, N'NumErrorLogs', @NumErrorLogs OUTPUT
select @NumErrorLogs
```